# OpenCV3.1 compilation error 'ffmpeg/avformat.h' file not found

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, cmake

On *MacOS 10.9.5 Mavericks*. I used homebrew to install `Python`, `cmake`, `ffmpeg`.
Entering `ffmpeg` in terminal shows it is installed.
I downloaded `Opencv3` and `opencv_contrib`

Then `cmake` with this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/stefan/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0dl/build \
    -D PYTHON2_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin \
    -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
    -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \
    -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON  -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/include \
    -D FFMPEG_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/Downloads/opencv_contrib-3.0.0/modules ..
```

Terminal output included this:

```
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 57.24.102)
--       format:                    YES (ver 57.25.100)
--       util:                      YES (ver 55.17.103)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.0.100)
--       resample:                  YES (ver 3.0.0)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
```

But `CMakeError.log` had this as its only error:

> ffmpeg/avformat.h file not found

The file does exist at

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/include/libavformat/avformat.h
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error if I properly specified the `FFMPEG` include directories in the `cmake` command. Also the variables `FMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR` and `FFMPEG_LIB_DIR` do not exist in the file, `CMakeLists.txt`. 

Does that make my use of those variables in the cake command useless?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with

```
brew uninstall ffmpeg
brew install ffmpeg --build-from-source
```

components needed are only available when the source is pulled down.
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6435